# Cypress method for choosing an if section depending on a string

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

How can I write this method correctly in cypress so that when I call for example `setToOffService('Online booking')` it knows how to go to the correct if and call the appropriate id for that string.

I hope I have provided all the important details

```
 setToOffService(name: string) : void {
    
        cy.get('#Service_IsActive').then(($name) => {
    
            if ($name.text().includes('Service is available')) {
                cy.get('#Service_IsActive').click({force:true});
            }
            else if ($name.text().includes('Online booking')) {
                cy.get('#Service_AllowOnlineScheduling').click({force:true});
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to alternate behavior based on what text displays in the app, or simply what you pass in to the function?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```js
cy.get('#Service_IsActive').then(($ele) => {
  if ($ele.text().trim() == name) {
    cy.get('#Service_IsActive').click({force: true})
  } else if ($ele.text().trim() == name) {
    cy.get('#Service_AllowOnlineScheduling').click({force: true})
  }
})
```

Comment: It is not working, any string I give it goes and executes the first sequence in if, it doesn't go into else if

Comment: then instead of `includes` use `==`. Updated the answer

Comment: No, It doesn't work that way either, it always appears "get #Service_IsActive" in Cypress Console, even if i have as string "Online booking", correspondent for else if

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the `name` parameter should control which element to click?

```js
setToOffService(name: string) : void {
    
  if (name === 'Service is available') {
    cy.get('#Service_IsActive').click();
  }
      
  if (name === 'Online booking') {
    cy.get('#Service_AllowOnlineScheduling').click();
  }
}


setToOffService('Service is available')  // clicks #Service_IsActive

setToOffService('Online booking')  // clicks #Service_AllowOnlineScheduling
```